# Using Bootstrap Dropdown - Focus Input via Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code below which is part of Bootstrap Framework.

My goal is to focus the input if click on `<a>name</a>` via Jquery's click/focus functionality. I already know its about the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute in the `a` link make it doesnt work. I am not really experienced. Hopefully anybody got some help for me!

```
<html>
<body>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> name </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
<li>
<form ...>                                      
<input type="text" id="4711" /> 
</form>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>



<script>
$('#dLabel').click(function() {
  $('#4711').focus();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your html code is wrong, you should close html tag after closing body tag not before

Answer (score 5):

You should put your code in document ready handler:

{for bootstrap, you could use a timeout as a simple workaround}

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uNrmS/5/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#dLabel').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){$('#login').focus();},0);
    });
    $('.dropdown input[type=text]').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you use jsfiddle to illustrate your problem as i don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: thank you for your fast response! basicly its working,yes. but the problem is in comprehension with bootstrap dropdown! i added bootstrap js library to fsfiddle that make it more clearly! plz take a lot into it. my hope was maybe to listen for the bootstrap dropdown function and then call the focus function. but again, i am not really expierienced, so i am relly glad if somebody can help out!

Comment: this is working perfectly! just one last question for my understanding! the setTimout() is set with the parameter 0, means no timeout. Why isnt that equal to using just $('#login').focus()?

Comment: Even setted to 0, a timeout will take few ms (8-15) to fired callback function. This is just enough to let bootstrap rendering his html/css which could interfered with any other handlers. In your case, i don't know exactly why bootstrap break triggered focus but seems relative to CSS pseudo classes.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution is use the label element with the for attribute instead of a element.

```
...
  <li class="dropdown">
    <label for="4711" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="icon-user"></i> name </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>
      <form ...>                                      
        <input type="text" id="4711" /> 
      </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to use a label and want to use a link then you can actually watch the events thrown by the dropdowns and handle it that way. You can see all the events at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events

For this case you would want to use the shown.bs.dropdown event so your code would be as such:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <li id="dropdownParent" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> name </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                <li>
                    <form ...>
                        <input type="text" id="4711" />
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
  $('#dropdownParent').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $('#4711').focus();
  });
</script>
```